# How to read spaces as characters in C++

Tags: c++, char, switch-statement, do-while, file-read

I want to read all characters from a .txt file, but my program is not reading the spaces and I don't know  why.
I also want to test all characters with a switch, but spaces are not detected as characters.
How to solve this problem?

PS: I want to solve this without getline

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define InFile "intra.txt"
#define OutFile "raspuns.txt"
using namespace std;
ifstream fin(InFile);
ofstream fout(OutFile);

int main()
{
long int i,valori[100],aux, contor;
char a[10000];


i=0;
contor = -1;
do
{
 contor++;
 i++;
 fin>>a[i];
 cout<<a[i]<<"\n";
 switch(a[i]){
 ...
 }
```

Comment: `fin >> std::noskipws;` once, right after you open it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! My best regards for you!

Comment: If you code with modern C++, change `#define InFile "intra.txt"` to `static constexpr auto InFile = "intra.txt"`. Your future co-workers will appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
std::ifstream file("../../temp.txt");
if(!file)return 0;
std::string line;

while (std::getline(file, line, '\0')){
    for(char ascii : line){
        std::cout<<(int)ascii << " ";
    }
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```